# Many terms has appeared as I try to derive $~ \lim_{ x \to \infty} \left( \sqrt{ x^2+a^2 } -x \right) =0 ~$

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, taylor-expansion, systems-of-equations

I want to prove the below equation .

$$  \lim_{ x \to \infty}  \left( \sqrt{ x^2+a^2 } -x \right)  =0 $$

$$  a,x \in \mathbb R_{> 0} $$

My tries so far are as the below .

$$  \lim_{ x \to \infty}  \left( \sqrt{ x^2+a^2 } -x \right)   $$

$$ = \lim_{ x \to \infty} \left\{ \sqrt{ x^2 \left( 1+ \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right) ^{2} \right)  } -x \right\}  $$

$$ = \lim_{ x \to \infty}  \left( x  \underbrace{ \sqrt{ 1+ \left( \frac{  a  }{ x   }  \right)^2  } }_{ \text{Defined this as} ~ f \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right) ~~.  }  -x   \right)  $$

One of the approaches to this problem is using a maclaurin series .

$$ f \left( \frac{  a  }{ x   }  \right)  = \displaystyle\sum_{ i=0 }^{ \infty  } \left( \frac{  f^{\left( i \right) }\left( 0 \right) \cdot \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)  ^{i}  }{  i!  }  \right)  ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{my general form of it }  $$

$$  f \left( \frac{  a  }{ x   }  \right) =\sqrt{ 1+ \left( \frac{  a  }{ x   }  \right)^2  }= \left( 1+ \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right) ^2 \right)  ^{\frac{1}{2} } $$

$$  f^{\left( 0 \right) }\left( \frac{  a  }{ x   }  \right)  = \left( 1+ \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right) ^2 \right)  ^{\frac{1}{2} } $$

$$  f^{\left( 1 \right) }\left( \frac{  a  }{ x   }  \right)= \frac{1}{2} \left( 1+ \left( \frac{ a }{ x }  \right) ^{2} \right) ^{-1/2}  \cdot \left( 2 \left( \frac{  a  }{ x   }  \right)  \right)  $$

$$ = \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right) \left( 1+ \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right)^{2}  \right)^{-1/2}  $$

$$   f^{\left( 2 \right) }\left( \frac{  a  }{ x   }  \right)= \left( 1+ \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right) ^{2} \right) ^{-1/2} + \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right) \left\{ -\frac{1}{2}\left(   1+ \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right) ^{2} \right) ^{-3/2}2 \left( \frac{  a  }{ x   }  \right)    \right\}   $$

$$ = \left( 1+ \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right) ^{2} \right) ^{-1/2} - \left( \frac{  a  }{ x   }  \right) ^{2} \left( 1+ \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right) ^{2} \right) ^{-3/2} $$

$$  f^{\left(3\right)}\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)=\left( -\frac{1}{2}  \right) \left( 1+ \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right) ^2 \right) ^{-3/2} \cdot  2 \left( \frac{  a  }{ x   }  \right) -2 \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{} \left( 1+ \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{2}  \right) ^{-3/2} - \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{2} \left\{ - \frac{  3  }{  2  } \left( 1+ \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{2}  \right) ^{-5/2} \cdot 2 \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{}  \right\}    $$

$$ = -\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{} \left( 1+ \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{2}  \right) ^{-3/2} -2 \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{} \left( 1+ \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{2}  \right) ^{-3/2} +3 \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{3} \left( 1+ \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{2}  \right) ^{-5/2}  $$

After done of the above calculations , I guessed that the below equation is held as we set $~ \left( \frac{  a }{  x  }  \right) =0 ~$ .

$$
    \forall i \in \mathbb{N}_{0}   ~\rightarrow~ f^{\left( i \right) } \left( 0 \right) = 
\begin{cases}
    0&~ ~~\leftrightarrow~~   i  \equiv 1 ~\left(\text{mod}\left( 2  \right)\right)    \\
    1&~ ~~\leftrightarrow~~   i  \equiv 0 ~\left(\text{mod}\left( 2  \right)\right) 
\end{cases}
$$

Brought again the below .

$$ f \left( \frac{  a  }{ x   }  \right)  = \displaystyle\sum_{ i=0 }^{ \infty  } \left( \frac{  f^{\left( i \right) }\left( 0 \right) \cdot \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)  ^{i}  }{  i!  }  \right)  ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{my general form of it }  $$

$$  f \left(\frac{a}{x}^{}\right) = \displaystyle\sum_{ i=0 }^{ \infty  } \left( \frac{1}{ \left( 2i \right)  ! } \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^{2i}  \right)  $$

$$ = \displaystyle\sum_{ i=0 }^{ \infty  } \frac{  a^{2i}  }{  \left( 2i \right)  ! \cdot x ^{2i}  }  $$

$$ = 1 + \displaystyle\sum_{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }  \frac{  a^{2i}  }{  \left( 2i \right) ! \cdot x ^{2i}  } $$

So , as the below is held , the goal is near .

$$  \lim_{ x \to \infty} f \left(\frac{  a }{  x  }\right) = 1  $$

The 2 doughts exists so far .

One of them is to derive the below .

$$
    \forall i\in \mathbb{N}_{0} ~\rightarrow~ f^{\left( i \right) } \left( 0 \right) = 
\begin{cases}
    0&~ ~~\leftrightarrow~~   i  \equiv 1 ~\left(\text{mod}\left( 2  \right)\right)    \\
    1&~ ~~\leftrightarrow~~   i  \equiv 0 ~\left(\text{mod}\left( 2  \right)\right) 
\end{cases}
$$

And the other dought is that , how to derive $~ \lim_{ x \to \infty} \displaystyle\sum_{ i=1 }^{ \infty  }  \frac{  a^{2i}  }{   \left( 2i \right) ! \cdot x ^{2i}  } = 0 ~$

I need your wisdom .

**p.s**

I should have searched more before doing this post but the internet connection was bad at that time so I hadn't the enough time to view the suggested posts .

Comment: Instead of using series you can use $\sqrt{x^2+a} - x = \frac{a}{\sqrt{x^2 + a} + x}$

Comment: why you torture yourself. just multiply and divide by conjugate

Comment: Definitely the comments above give the easy way. But also, $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{a^{2i}}{(2i)!\, x^{2i}} = \cosh \left(\frac{a}{x}\right)$$

Comment: WLOG, $a=0$ (see why ?). Then $x(\sqrt{1+x^{-2}}-1)=x\left(1+\dfrac{x^{-2}}2+o(x^{-2})-1\right)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{ x \to \infty}\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-x & =\lim_{ x \to \infty}(\sqrt{x^2+a^2}-x)\frac{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x}\\
&=\lim_{ x \to \infty}\frac{x^2-x^2+a^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x}\\
&=\lim_{ x \to \infty}\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}+x} \\ & =0.
\end{align*}